# Cocoapods path issue (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, afnetworking, cocoapods

I'm an XCode noob and I'm getting the following error when using Cocoapods to install AFNetworking:

`ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking`

Here's the composition of my bridge.h file:

`#import <AFNetworking/AFNetworking.h>`

Here's a screenshot of the Project navigation include the full error message, can someone help?

[image: ERROR: ld: library not found for -lPods-AFNetworking]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see from your screenshots you have opened the `.xcodeproj` file. When working with cocoapods you have to run via terminal:

```
pod install
```

in the project directory and then you should open the `.xcworkspace` file instead of the `.xcodeproj` file for your project (the `.xcworkspace` file is generated with the `pod install` command). This opens also the pods project which contains all the dependency projects contained in your `podfile`.